# Не удаётся отправить значение EditText по Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

Прошу сильно ногами не бить,работаю с Java недавно, но сказали сделать приложение, которое должно считывать значения поля EditText и пересылать его по Bluetooth, но, когда я попытался сделать это возникли трудности.  Проблема в том, что у меня не определяется 
**public void sendCommand**, хотя я и прописываю его в **onCreate**.   Заранее спасибо!

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.car_55;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.PermissionChecker;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;


import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;


public class MainActivity<bluetooth> extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "bluetooth1";


    int Speed3;
    int Speed2;
    EditText Speed1;
    Button start;


    private Button Act_Change, start_search;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;


    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    public Integer[] dataToSend = {1,3,3,3,3,3,3};
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<String> pairedDeviceArrayList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> pairedDeviceAdapter;
    public static BluetoothSocket clientSocket;
    private Button buttonStartControl;
    private OutputStream outStream;
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private static String address = "21:13:01:80:20";  //Вместо “00:00” Нужно нудет ввести MAC нашего bluetooth


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //обязательная строчка
        //прикрепляем ранее созданную разметку
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //цепляем кнопку из разметки
        Button buttonStartFind = findViewById(R.id.start_search);
        Button start = findViewById(R.id.start);
        //цепляем layout, в котором будут отображаться найденные устройства
        listView = findViewById(R.id.List_device);
        new Intent();
        addListenerOnButton();
        OnButtonClick();
        Bundle came = getIntent().getExtras();
        sendCommand(String.valueOf(Speed2));

        try {
            outStream.write(joinArrayOfInts(dataToSend));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        {


        }


        //устанавливаем действие на клик
        buttonStartFind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                               @Override
                                               public void onClick(View v) {
                                                   //если разрешения получены (функция ниже)
                                                   bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                                                   if (bluetoothEnabled()) { //если блютуз включен (функция ниже)
                                                       findArduino(); //начать поиск устройства (функция ниже)
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           }
        );
    }
    public int joinArrayOfInts(Integer[] array){
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("/");

        for(Integer i: array){
            s.append(Integer.toString(i));
            s.append("/");
        }

        return Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
    }


    private void sendCommand(String Speed2) {
        //блютуз умеет отправлять только байты, поэтому переводим
        byte[] Come = Speed2.getBytes();

        try {
            outStream.write(Come);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Отправление" + Come);
    }









    private boolean permissionGranted() {
        //если оба разрешения получены, вернуть true
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN}, 0);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean bluetoothEnabled() {
//если блютуз включен, вернуть true, если нет, вежливо попросить пользователя его включить
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 0);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void findArduino() {
        //получить список доступных устройств
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (pairedDevice.size() > 0) { //если есть хоть одно устройство
            pairedDeviceArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); //создать список
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevice) {
                //добавляем в список все найденные устройства
                //формат: "уникальный адрес/имя"
                pairedDeviceArrayList.add(device.getAddress() + "/" + device.getName());
            }
        }
        //передаем список адаптеру, пригождается созданный ранее item_device.xml
        pairedDeviceAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_device, R.id.item_device_textView, pairedDeviceArrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(pairedDeviceAdapter);
        //на каждый элемент списка вешаем слушатель
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                //через костыль получаем адрес
                String itemMAC = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().split("/", 2)[0];
                //получаем класс с информацией об устройстве
                BluetoothDevice connectDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(itemMAC);
                try {
                    //генерируем socket - поток, через который будут посылаться данные
                    Method m = connectDevice.getClass().getMethod(
                            "createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});

                    clientSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(connectDevice, 1);
                    clientSocket.connect();
                    if (clientSocket.isConnected()) {
                        //если соединение установлено, завершаем поиск
                        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendData(String message) {
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

        Log.d(TAG, "...Посылаем данные: " + message + "...");

        try {
            outStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
            if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00"))
                msg = msg + ".\n\nВ переменной address у вас прописан 00:00:00:00:00:00, вам необходимо прописать реальный MAC-адрес Bluetooth модуля";
            msg = msg + ".\n\nПроверьте поддержку SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " на Bluetooth модуле, к которому вы подключаетесь.\n\n";


        }
        if (outStream != null) {

            if (outStream != null) {
            }
        }
    }


    private void addListenerOnButton() {
        Act_Change = findViewById(R.id.Act_Change);

        Act_Change.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Act_Change.setText("DONE");
                        Act_Change.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
                    }

                }
        );
        Act_Change.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity3.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }


    private void OnButtonClick() {
        final EditText Speed1 = findViewById(R.id.Speed1);
        start = findViewById(R.id.start);


        final Button Start = findViewById(R.id.start);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                     public void onClick(View v) {
                                         try {
                                             Speed2 = Integer.parseInt(Speed1.getText().toString());
                                         } catch (Exception e) {
                                             //Выполните необходимые действия в случае ошибки

                                         }
                                         System.out.println("Считывание" + Speed2);
                                     }


                                 }
        );
    }


    public void sendCommand(String Speed2, String Time1) {
        //блютуз умеет отправлять только байты, поэтому переводим
        byte[] speedArray = Speed2.getBytes();
        byte[] timeArray = Time1.getBytes();
        try {
            outStream.write(timeArray);
            outStream.write(speedArray);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Отправление" + speedArray);
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
2019-04-16 23:08:29.373 6926-6926/com.example.car_55 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.car_55, PID: 6926
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.car_55/com.example.car_55.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[])' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[])' on a null object reference
        at com.example.car_55.MainActivity.sendCommand(MainActivity.java:122)
        at com.example.car_55.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:76)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
```

Comment: в коде `sendCommand(String.valueOf(Speed2));` проверьте что есть тут: `String.valueOf(Speed2)`

Comment: у вас приходит `null` объект, а вы пытаетесь вызвать у него какой-то метод, вот и все ломаетсчя